# How to add an image in the last page of pdf using iText?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

How do i add an image on the last page of existing PDF document. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the text from the PDF using the same **ITEXT** library.Try this

```
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(INPUTFILE);
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    PdfTextExtractor parser =new PdfTextExtractor(new PdfReader("C:/Text.pdf"));
    parser.getTextFromPage(3); // Extracting the content from a particular page.
```

After you have add your data ,You can  load images either from file or from a URL, like this:

```
   Image image1 = Image.getInstance("watermark.png");
   document.add(image1);

   String imageUrl = "http://applause-voice.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/1hello.jpg";
   Image image2 = Image.getInstance(new URL(imageUrl));
   document.add(image2);
```

If you will add this code at the end of your Java Program , then the image will automatically comes at the end of your page.

Comment: I have a pdf document with 5 pages. I need to edit that document by adding one image on last page.

Comment: What your existing pdf contain images, texts , anything else?

Comment: Existing pdf contains Text only.

Comment: @Santhosh Edited my answer.Have a look.Now try to do it.

Comment: Compilation Error : The constructor PdfTextExtractor(PdfReader) is undefined

Answer (score 4):

The following example adds an image to the second page of an existing pdf using Itext 5.

```
    String src = "c:/in.pdf;
    String dest = "c:/out.pdf";
    String IMG = "C:/image.jpg";

    try {

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        com.itextpdf.text.Image image = com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(IMG);
        image.setAbsolutePosition(36, 400);
        PdfContentByte over = stamper.getOverContent(2);
        over.addImage(image);
        stamper.close();
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: I have a java Nullpointer exception when I use this snippet. Line over.addImage() is the culprit!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for me was to create a new in-memory PDF document with the image I want to add, then copy this page to the original document.

```
 // Create a separate doc for image
var pdfDocWithImageOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
var pdfDocWithImage = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(pdfDocWithImageOutStream).setSmartMode(true));
var docWithImage = new Document(pdfDocWithImage, destinationPdf.getDefaultPageSize());

// Add image to the doc
docWithImage.add(image);

// Close the doc to save data
docWithImage.close();
pdfDocWithImage.close();

// Open the same doc for reading
pdfDocWithImage = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(pdfDocWithImageOutStream.toByteArray())));
docWithImage = new Document(pdfDocWithImage, destinationPdf.getDefaultPageSize());

// Copy page to original (destinationPdf)
pdfDocWithImage.copyPagesTo(1, pdfDocWithImage.getNumberOfPages(), destinationPdf);

docWithImage.close();
pdfDocWithImage.close();
```